# C# program using up too much CPU?

Tags: c#, performance, loops, timer, cpu

I have a program that starts constantly juggles between 3 separate timers.

The main thread of my application has a while loop which constantly checks if a global variable has been set to true and if it has, it will stop one timer and launch two other ones - one continuously, another to stop it automatically if it isn't commanded to stop for whatever reason.

This while loop has a condition of (1==1) so that it runs forever.

In the task manager (XP) I see that my program is using up 50% of cpu on a more or less idle system.

Is there a way to decrease that number by decreasing the speed of the while loop or something?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you're keeping 3 threads running with infinite loops?
Try check out this: [Thread.Interrupts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx) as endless loops are to be avoided!

Comment: Does your loop ever Sleep or Wait?    If it's sitting there spinning around non-stop, then that would explain the CPU usage (possibly using 100% of a single core?).     Perhaps if you told it to Sleep for a few milliseconds at the end of each iteration, there'd be less CPU usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to decrease that number by decreasing the speed of the while loop or something?

Yes, you could insert a call to `Thread.Sleep(n)`. With a granularity of ~20 ms.

But the far better option would be using a Waithandle.
Your main thread would Wait on the handle and the end of the timer code would signal it to wake up.

Comment: Thanks for a quick and dirty fix : )

Comment: Even passing in a value of 0 is often sufficient to "yield enough" to avoid 100% CPU grabbing. (The actual time yielded is actually a fair bit more than "0" due to Windows scheduling granularity ~ "20ms")

Comment: @pst: Sleep(0) is problematic under some circumstances. Use Sleep(1) as a rule.

Comment: Any reason not to use a timer object? I've found it cleaner and easier. Instead of having to code interrupts to stop the loop when done with it, you can simply dispose of the Timer object.

Answer (score 12):

> Is there a way to decrease that number by decreasing the speed of the while loop or something?

Just stop doing a busy loop. There are better ways of coordinating events between threads. Consider using `Monitor.Wait`/`Pulse`, or `AutoResetEvent` / `ManualResetEvent`. Basically, the thread that sets the global variable should signal that it's done so. Alternatively, if your main thread wouldn't be doing *anything* else, why not add a normal C# event so that whenever the variable is changed, the event is raised and the appropriate action can be taken?

Answer (score 6):

Your program performs [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), which is a bad practice. You should change your logic so that instead of looping, you block on some kind of synchronization primitive (also known as [wait handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Blocking on a wait handle is not an option for the UI thread, so you would have to create three threads in total and implement the scheme like this:

1. The UI thread does not concern itself at all with what other threads to. No looping, no sleeping, no blocking.
2. The new "controller" thread would start the existing "worker" thread and then immediately block (e.g. on an event that is not signaled). It will remain in this state, without consuming CPU, until the event is signaled (i.e. the "worker" completes).
3. The "worker" thread would run its course and then signal the event.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sleep the threat for a given number of ms. Look at the Thread.sleep() function and place it within your while loop.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to slow down a loop like this is to just add a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); For every iteration the process will sleep for 100 ms and it will not use 50% cpu anymore.

Comment: Jon's answer "Just stop doing a busy loop" is the best advice. But just adding a sleep is the quick and dirty fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Threads instead of Timer it costlier than Thread. Or Please check the thread state of your time which stopped before start another. You can improve performance by cutting down your code logic.

Hope this will helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

While the answers here aren't wrong per-say, They don't really address a lot of issues with doing `while(true)` loops which is what `while(1==1)` is.

First of, even if the loop is running the entire time your application is in use, you will want to shit it down at some point, say when the user exits your application, because if you have a thread with a constant loop, even if the user closes the UI window, the process will remain until the thread exits (which is never in a while true loop) or until the user becomes wise and closes it from the task manager.

You COULD solve this by putting a true conditional in the while conditional check that references a accessible property outside the loop.

Example:

```
private bool RequestExit = false;
private Thread MyLoopThread;
private void MyLoop()
{
  while (!RequestExit)
  {
    //Do stuff!
    Sleep(1);
  }
}
public void StartLoop()
{
  RequestExit = false;
  MyLoopThread = new Thread(MyLoop);
  MyLoopThread.Start();
}
public void StopLoop()
{
  RequestExit = true;
}
```

That is the bare-bones and doesn't even get into avoiding double launches or double shutdown events.

A much cleaner way would be to set an arbitrary interval that you want to pool at, 10ms or so should do just fine for pretty much any real time event, and trigger an method to fire at that interval.

```
private Timer DoStuffTimer;
private void DoStuffMethod(object obj = null)
{
  //Do stuff!
}
public void StartLoop()
{
  DoStuffTimer = new Timer(DoStuffMethod,null,10,10);
}
public void StopLoop()
{
  DoStuffTimer.Dispose();
}
```